# location.href in echo doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some little problem with my php `echo`. I have a JavaScript link function and that doesnt work ,because in html it shows this type of link `onclick="location.href="http://www.link.com/";"` As you can see ,this dont work with this syntax. But with this `onclick="location.href='http://www.link.com/';"` that works well

My php look like this

```
...
echo '<div ... onclick="location.href="'.get_permalink($recent["ID"]).'";">..</div>';
...
```

What I need to do ,to this works properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You used the wrong quotes and/or did not escape them.

Here is the solution:

```
echo '<div ... onclick="location.href=\''.get_permalink($recent["ID"]).'\';">..</div>';
```

Cleaner/better is to NOT use HTML in your PHP, like this:

```
<div ... onclick="location.href='<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>';">..</div>
```

Comment: oh, yeah, my mistake :/ Thank you!